# What is the most appropriate time frame to apply to a Postdoc?

Tags: postdocs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How long before PhD graduation should I start applying for post-doc positions?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/5301/how-long-before-phd-graduation-should-i-start-applying-for-post-doc-positions)

I'm about to start a Postdoctoral program of 1 year, after that, there is a high possibility that the project won't go on. Hence, I have to find a new position.

What would it be a good time frame to start contacting professors to find a second postdoc, I found that applying very early usually ended up in me being not a suitable candidate because I had no immediate availability.

I know that there is no one size fits all time frame, but in your experience, what would be a better practice?

Comment: Related (possible duplicate): http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/5301/102

Answer (score 3):

Charles answer here (https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/5303/4231) applies to your case. Some positions will start right away and some positions will have a fixed start date set in the future. I suggest you start looking around 6 months into your 1 year postdoc, at first focus on positions starting later: that info should be in the job advertisment. Then, if you have not found something suitable, focus on positions starting right away when you approach the end of your postdoc.

Do not wait until your postdoc is finished to look for a new position.