# How long before PhD graduation should I start applying for academic jobs

Tags: mathematics, job-search, asia

I hope this is not a duplicate, I saw this question:
[How long before PhD graduation should I start applying for post-doc positions?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/5301/how-long-before-phd-graduation-should-i-start-applying-for-post-doc-positions)

However, I didn't find any analogous question for applying for jobs (academic). Is there a certain timeline to look for jobs?

In particular, do I need to have completed the PhD or fulfill any requirement (e.g. submitted thesis) before I can look for jobs?

I am considering any kind of academic job, tenured, or non-tenured jobs like lecturer and adjunct posts.

I am looking at mid-tier universities in Asia, in applied mathematics and related fields.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what kind of positions you have in mind, and what field you are in? In the life sciences, the ones you've listed all require you to have some postdoc experience (maybe not technically, but certainly in practice).

Comment: Too broad. Please one question at a time. Specify your country and your target countries.

Comment: @Hexal I am looking at Asian universities.

Comment: @Gerhard I am looking at mid-tier universities in Asia, in applied mathematics and related fields.

Comment: Provide an estimate when you'd obtain your PhD in your application and better apply early than late.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For postdoc positions: apply approximately 3-6 months before graduation.

For (UK, AU)-lecturer and assistant professor positions: apply approximately a year before the graduation.

Usually, you have to be graduated by the first day you start with your job duties, though exceptions exist.

Comment: I'd add that in the US at least, some adjunct/lecturer positions are posted much later than postdocs, as schools figure out their needs after filling/failing to fill various positions, so you should expect to have a long hiring season, sometimes up until almost the first day of classes.

Comment: @Mathprof Feel free to add it to my answer if you wish.